# Play MediaPlayer audio between Activities, but pause/resume when background loses focus and is brought back?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I've spent nearly the entire day trying to find a solution for a specific MediaPlayer problem. I'd like my MediaPlayer's audio to keep playing when the user switches Activities within my app, but to stop when switching to another app (Home button, Recent Apps button, etc.) and resume when the App is brought into focus again. I just can't seem to get a solution that works this way though. It's not that I don't know where to begin, but every solution I've tried was complicated, and in the end just didn't work. It seems like I just need the App to be able to tell when an Activity stops from switching Activities, and from the App losing focus.

I can't imagine a situation like this is so uncommon that there isn't a neat, elegant solution to solve it. Could anyone please help me figure it out? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to implement a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and a  [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) that listens for the desired actions and/or key presses (Home button, etc) using an intent-filter. The Android media player source can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music). The two classes you want to look at are [MediaButtonIntentReceiver](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music/blob/master/src/com/android/music/MediaButtonIntentReceiver.java) and [MediaPlaybackService](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music/blob/master/src/com/android/music/MediaPlaybackService.java).

Answer (score 4):

I think that the best way to share MediaPleer between activities is android Service.
Create a Service to hold MediaPlayer. Your activities bind to service in onResume and unbind in onPause. Service always knows if someone binded to it. So if no one binded (there are no your running activities) it stops playing.
google "android MediaPlayer from Service"

Comment: This sounds perfect, I'll check into it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

A service might be the way to go. With a service or not though it can often be a sign that the program you designed isn't as robust as it should be.  Even if you do create a service, you will still need to know when to pause and when to resume.

I implemented a simple solution that seems to work for me without properly refactoring the whole app to have a better application engine:

After starting the mediaPlayer in the initial activity in which you want the music to begin:

In the initial and each subsequent activity, create a member variable:
private boolean mStopTheMusic = true;

Then in EACH activity that you want the music to continue playing and or stopping appropriately override the following:  (note: stopping properly would be when any other app comes to the foreground instead of yours. These are appropriate times to stop the music)
And anytime YOU programmatically start a New activity on top of the current, set mStopTheMusic = false, so your background music doesn't stop.

```
    @Override 
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        mStopTheMusic  = true;
        if (!MusicPlayer.IsMusicPlaying())
            MusicPlayer.StartMusic();  
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() 
    {      
        super.onPause();
        if (mStopTheMusic)
          MusicPlayer.PauseMusic(); 
    }

   @Override 
   public void onBackPressed()
   {        
       mStopTheMusic = false;
       super.onBackPressed();   
   }
```